# Can I force the passwd command to use MD5 hash (and not crypt)?

Tags: ldap, passwd, md5

How can I force the passwd command to use MD5 hash and not to use crypt? I need to get the passwd command to talk to the ldap server (which it does) and use MD5 when I change passwords for the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Linux: set value of ENCRYPT_METHOD in /etc/login.defs to MD5.

Comment: MD5 (was and) is the choosen ENCRYPT_METHOD in /etc/login.defs - but passwd still makes {crypt} hashes in the LDAP-base.

Comment: And it says pam_password md5 in ldap.conf...

Comment: Try this: http://www.fusionnetwork.us/index.php/articles/linux-tutorials/enable-ldap-password-change-on-linux-using-passwd-command/ the author reports a success.

Comment: This is beginning to annoy me... if I follow the tutorial pam_password exop gives me SSHA hashes - and if I change it back to pam_password md5 I get crypt hashes. WHY!? :-)

Comment: "pam_password exop" in /etc/ldap.conf makes passwd use the password policy from the ldap server (in my case SSHA). I changed the policy in the server to MD5 and it worked. Now changes password with passwd is made with the MD5 hash - and I can happily sync all my users (and passwords) with Google Apps!

Answer (score 2):

Set the following in your `/etc/login.defs` file:

```
MD5_CRYPT_ENAB yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the authconfig command like so:

```
authconfig --enablemd5
```

Just search in the man page.